# How to remove style on second click?

Tags: jquery, html

i got a box that is green as default and then changes color to red when you click on it the first time. how can I get the box to change back to green when you click on it a second time?

```
<div class="box1" id="1"> </div>

.box1 {
top: 1%;
left: 1%;
right: 1%;
height: 6%;
position: absolute;
background-color: #68E000;
padding-left: 2%;
padding-top: 0%;
cursor: pointer;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#1").click(function() {
        $("#1").css("background-color", "#FA0000");
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing, cross-browser, is to use another class:

```
.box1.toggled {
    background-color: #FA0000;
}
```

and then toggle it:

```
$("#1").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

Note also that you can use `$(this)` inside the click handler rather than looking up the element again.

**Live Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#1").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("toggled");
  });
});
```

```css
.box1 {
  top: 1%;
  left: 1%;
  right: 1%;
  height: 6%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #68E000;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-top: 0%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.box1.toggled {
  background-color: #FA0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1" id="1"></div>
```

---

In a comment you've said you want to avoid using another class. I can't see why you'd want to do that, but we can make it work with a flag instead:

```
$("#1").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var isRed = !$this.data("isRed");
  $this.data("isRed", isRed);
  $(this).css("background-color", isRed ? "#FA0000" : "");
});
```

Note how to make this scale well, we store the flag on the element, rather than in its own variable.

**Live Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#1").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var isRed = !$this.data("isRed");
    $this.data("isRed", isRed);
    $(this).css("background-color", isRed ? "#FA0000" : "");
  });
});
```

```css
.box1 {
  top: 1%;
  left: 1%;
  right: 1%;
  height: 6%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #68E000;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-top: 0%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1" id="1"></div>
```

But note that this mixes styling with code and is more complicated than keeping styling and code separate and using a class.

---

Side note: While `$("#1")` works, it's technically invalid. CSS `id` selectors cannot start with a digit. It just happens that `$("#1")` works because jQuery optimizes it into a call to `getElementById`. But if you combined it with anything (for instance, `$("#1 span")` to select `span` elements inside the `#1` element), it would fail.

For this reason, I avoid `id` values starting with digits. If you *do* use them, you can select them with a valid selector via escaping (which is hard to read) or an attribute selector: `$('[id="1"]')`. But then jQuery can't optimize it to a call to `getElementById` (though that optimization isn't usually important).

Comment: That is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: @kippi: Why would you want to avoid using another class? It's simple, it keeps the styling separate from the code. (And that would have been useful information to put in the question -- both that you wanted to avoid using another class, and why.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the id. I just happen to have a lot of these divs and I would like to keep it as shoort as possible

Comment: @kippi: I've added an option for not using a class, but a class would be best practices.

Comment: Thank you very much for that